# Convert a list with three arguments {x0,x1, step} into an equidistant table?

Tags: list-manipulation, conversion

How can I convert a list such as:

```
a = {1, 2, 0.1}
```

into sequence so that I can pass them into a function, e.g. I want to be able to do something like this

```
Range[a]
```

so that the output will be:

> 1, 1.1, 1.2, ... , 2.0

Comment: I modified the title to make it a bit more informative and added some formatting - for your next questions please have a look at the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq) and the [markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Range function in this way:

```
Range[1, 2, 0.1]
```

to get

```
{1.,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.}
```

If the problem is how to pass the parameter `a` you can use:

1- Using `Apply`.

```
a = {1, 2, 0.1}
Range@@a
```

The `Apply` operator (`@@`) "decapitates" the `List` head from list `a` and changes it by `Range`.

2- Using `Sequence`

```
a = {1, 2, 0.1};
Range[Sequence @@ a]
```

It's useful when you have another variables to pass. That's not your case, but I just wrote to be more didactical.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Taking the last line of the question even more literally than Mr.Wizard

```
a = {1, 2, 0.1};
r = Range @@ a;
Row[{Sequence @@ r[[1 ;; 3]], "...", r[[-1]]}, ","]
```

> 1., 1.1, 1.2, ..., 2.

Comment: The audacity! +1 :-)

Comment: you need to go 1 level more literal and implement the cream bg with an orange dotted border on the left :D

Comment: @rm-rf that wasn't in the original or it would have been really funny.

Answer (score 3):

... you can also use `ReplaceAll`:

```
 a={1,2,.1};
 a /. List->Range (* ReplaceAll *)
 (* {1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.} *)
```

or, `ReplacePart`:

```
 ReplacePart[a, 0 -> Range]
 (* {1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.} *)
```

or, set `Part` zero to `Range` (re-assign head):

```
 b=a; b[[0]]=Range;b
```

Comment: +1 for symbol[[0]]=newHead.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the last line of your question literally:

```
a = {1, 2, 0.1};

Row[Range @@ a, ","]
```

> ```
> 1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.
> ```

Also, to illustrate an alternative data format:

```
a = Sequence[1, 2, 0.1]

Range[a]
```

> ```
> {1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that's also very useful to know for future use. As you can probably tell, I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
a = {1, 2, 0.1};
Table[i, {i, ##}] & @@ a

(*{1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.}*)
```